# How to create a barplot for a column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I am not sure why my code doesn't show proper barplot (plus I am not sure if I am doing it right at all?)

```
> chas=Boston$chas
> chas.frequency=table(chas)
> barplot(chas.frequency)
```

[image]

I am not sure what was wrong with the above code but after resetting the data to its default and trying the following code I got it working:

```
table(Boston$chas)
barplot(table(Boston$chas))
```

Comment: Did you recode `Boston$chas`? This code works fine for me except `Boston$chas` is a vector of zeros and ones so the labels on the plot are just 0 and 1

Comment: Yeah, I recode it to `on` and `off`

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(Boston$chas)`?

Comment: I can exactly replicate your `barplot` if the tabulation results in 0 cases for "on" and 0 cases for "off". I assume something has gone wrong with your data.